# JavaFX CSS hover vs onMouseEntered

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I'm using JavaFX, and in my CSS I have

```
.button:hover{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Which works. But when I try to use another property,

```
.button:onMousePressed {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Or `onMouseEntered` (which I expected to be the same behavior as `hover`), nothing happens. Is there something fundamentally different about how these work?

Comment: Are you using javafx 2 or 8 ?

Comment: BTW, you say `MouseEntered` and write `MousePressed`, is that a typo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those simply aren't valid CSS pseudoclasses for a button. You are probably looking for

```
.button:armed {
    /* ... */
}
```

The valid pseudoclasses are listed in the [CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button)

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes when I'm allowed to. You nailed it. Didn't think to look for a JavaFX specific CSS guide.